# Соблюдение ударений в иностранных именах

Tags: фонетика, ономастика

"А не замахнуться ли нам на Виль**я**ма нашего Шексп**и**ра?" - думаю, все помнят эту фразу. И также искажаются в русском языке многие иностранные имена. Мы говорим "Джордж ВашингтОн", ОскАр Уайльд, ЛиверпУль, АкИра Курсава и т.д.
Почему происходит такое смещение ударений и грамотно ли вообще так говорить или надо все-таки говорить так, как произносится в языках оригинала?

Answer (score 1):

Вполне грамотно. По-русски имена не обязаны подчиняться иностранным нормам. А происходит это потому, что у нас свои правила. Нам так удобнее говорить на нашем русском языке. Или кто-то когда-то решил, что так удобнее, и ему поверили.

Answer (score 0):

1. Сразу можно сказать, что правильное произношение  иностранного имени  должно соответствовать требованию русских орфоэпических словарей.
2. Ставить ударение по образцу оригинала нужно в том случае, если  вы переходите на язык оригинала.
3. Ударение меняется в том случае, если фонетика слова неудобна для русского языка. В частности, это касается первого ударного слога в многосложных словах.